# How to make neural network work with sklearn CountVectorizer in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, sequential, countvectorizer

so I have a project with multi output predictions (continuous float type) and I was testing multiple models. I am now stuck at a neural network because I keep getting this error in the model.fit function:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:259 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + display_shape(x.shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 200 but received input with shape (None, 3386)
```

What is weird is that it worked for a while with a small training set (saw all the epochs summary and execution was ok) and then when I changed to the actual bigger training set, I get this error. And I got it the first time when I tried with the first training set as well, but then somehow it worked.

At first, I got this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[2] = [0,1540] is out of order. Many sparse ops require sorted indices.
    Use `tf.sparse.reorder` to create a correctly ordered copy.

 [Op:SerializeManySparse]
```

then I added `.toarray()` to my input data and since then I get the one above (with axis=-1)

My X_train is the result of a CountVectorizer function (returns a csr matrix). I have tried various other approaches like reshaping or transforming to SparseTensor but I still get this error.

And the result of `X_train.shape` is `(200, 3386)` - not (None,3386) like it says in the error.

I'll leave you with some code with how I get the input/output vectors and the model

```
#prepare training data
X_train_raw = df_train.msg.values
X_train_clean = np.asarray(preprocess(X_train_raw))
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_clean).toarray()
Y_train = df_train.drop(['id'],axis=1).drop(['msg'],axis=1).values

.........

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, input_dim=200, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2))

model.compile(loss='mse', 
 optimizer='adam',
 metrics=['mae'])


model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=2)
predicted_validation = model.predict(X_validation)
mse_value, mae_value = model.evaluate(X_validation, Y_validation, verbose=0)
test_loss, test_metrics= model.evaluate(X_validation, Y_validation, verbose=0)

print('test loss', test_loss)
print('test metrics', test_metrics)

predicted_scores_test = model.predict(X_test)
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions! Maybe I'm not using the Sequential model well, I'm new to ML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your first layer, you should be specifying `input_dim=3386`: this is the number of features your data has.  Or, even better, since different datasets in will produce different number of words in the `CountVectorizer`, use `input_dim=len(vectorizer.vocabulary_)` so you don't have to change it anytime you change your data.

> And the result of `X_train.shape` is `(200, 3386)` - not (None,3386) like it says in the error.

The `200` as the first dimension of your input gets replaced by `None` because the shape seen by the network will depend on how you batch samples for training.